# Android 9.0 - MediaPlayer throws an exception on stream playback. Code: -1004, type: 1

Tags: android, https, media-player, android-9.0-pie, cleartext

My stream works pefectly with `android.media.MediaPlayer` on a number of devices: Samsung, Xiaomi, Huawei etc. However, recently devices started to receive Android 9.x updates. My stream **stopped working** on OnePlus 6 after installing **Android 9.x update**.

I'm receiving the following native error from `MediaPlayer`:

**type: 1, code: -1004**

or in other words: **what: 1, extra: -1004**

what: MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN, extra: MEDIA_ERROR_IO

First of all: check whether you're streaming from `https` source.

What else could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

From Android 9.x **Opt out of cleartext traffic** policy became the default one. So to enable http fallback in your apps you need to specifically define the policy in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Cleartext (using the unencrypted HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS) can be restored by adding:

```
<application
   [...]
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
   [...] />
```

Check whether the policy is turned on like this: `NetworkSecurityPolicy.isCleartextTrafficPermitted()`

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)